# Using @container with Sass variables

Tags: sass

I am trying to use the @container directive for breakpoints. It's working when I directly set the desired breakpoint like this:

```scss
@container (max-width: 992px) { // working
    span {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

However, when using variable for `992px` it doesn't work. To asure that I used the variable correctly I added another style (`max-height`) which is working well.

```scss
max-height: $tablet; // results in max-height: 992px;

@container (max-width: $tablet) { // not working
    span {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: `@container (max-width: #{$tablet}) {...}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Amaury pointed out in the comments, I had to use the following syntax for using the variable:

```scss
@container (max-width: #{$tablet}) {
    span {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```